# TicTactics Presentation

Tags: c#, game, wpf, xaml, community-challenge

This is my take at the current [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/weekend-challenge-reboot), at least the *presentation* part.

As I chose to write a WPF application for my game, and this is my very first time fiddling with a `UniformGrid` and `ItemsControl`, I'd like to know if I've done any beginner mistakes.

#### MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="TicTactics.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicTactics.UI"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:TicTactics;assembly=TicTactics"
        Title="TicTactics" Height="600" Width="600">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GlassBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkSlateBlue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="Border.Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="White" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.425" Color="AliceBlue" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="PaleTurquoise" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.99" Color="White" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="GridBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SlateBlue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#AAF0F8FF" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackColorKey}}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Board.Cells}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" MinWidth="360" 
                                 MinHeight="{Binding Path=MinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                 Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="SmallBoard">
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource GlassBorder}">
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource GridBorder}">
                            <local:SmallBoardView DataContext="{Binding Value}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### SmallBoardView

```
<UserControl x:Class="TicTactics.UI.SmallBoardView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicTactics.UI"
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:TicTactics;assembly=TicTactics"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CellBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SlateBlue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#6AFFFFFF" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackColorKey}}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="BoardCell">
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource CellBorder}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Value.Value, Converter={local:CellValueImageConverter}}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

#### Result

[image]

As the window gets resized, the game board and its contents scale perfectly well, all I'm missing is `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` values to prevent the user from making the window so small the grid gets clipped.

Anything else?

---

There's also [some C# code to be reviewed for this project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41029/tictactics-gameboard-logic)

Comment: Why do the large squares have double borders?

Comment: @svick I guess higher transparency on the inner border would make it more obvious, the outer border has an angle gradient; the inner border makes it more (too much?) subtle. Both have a small margin, which makes the boards appear to have a double border. Shortly put, it's intentional... but I'm no UI/UX designer, feel free to suggest a better-looking "glass" effect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `<Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#AAF0F8FF" />` - `Border.` prefix should be redundant, as you specify target type in `Style`.
2. `<Image Source="{Binding Value.Value, Converter={local:CellValueImageConverter}}" Stretch="Uniform" />` a) i think in such simple cases where you have like two possible states a `DataTrigger` is superior to spawning yet another converter. b) wasnt `Value` nullable? Wont it throw an exception if `HasValue == false`?

Apart from that your markup looks pretty clean to me.